# Is there a way to retrieve the saved audiences under an ad account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to retrieve all the saved audiences under an adaccount. I was able to retrieve the custom audiences couldn't find a way to get the saved audiences. Is there a way to do that.

Comment: I am facing same problem. In earlier days `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/reachestimate?` was working fine. And Now this is not available.